# bash script to list all directories in a path withescape charectes and CD into each to perform action

Tags: bash, escaping, spaces

I am trying to write a script to list all directories in a path. go to each directory and rename one .srt file in each directory with the name of .mp4 file (less extension)  in the same sub directory.
each subdirectory has one .mp4 and one .srt file.

in return i get this $ ./change.sh ./change.sh: line 2: Lawless: command not found here LawLess (1111) is name of first directory in list of directories.

code is

```
#!/bin/bash
yourPathEscaped=$(`find $1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | cut -d . -f2 | cut -d \/ -f2 | sed 's/ /\\ /g' | sed 's/,/\\, /g' | sed -e s/\'/\\\\\'/g`)
for dirm in $yourPathEscaped

do
  cd $dirm
  echo $dirm
  for f in `ls *.mp4 | grep -Po '.*(?=\.)'`; do echo $f; mv *.srt $f.srt; ls ; done
  for f in `ls *.mkv | grep -Po '.*(?=\.)'`; do echo $f; mv *.srt $f.srt; ls ; done

cd ..

done
```

Comment: *getting errors* is a meaningless problem description, unless you give us the information about what those *errors* are specifically. Do you get an error message? If so, what is the exact, complete message? If not, how do you know it's an *error*? You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [ask], before you begin posting.

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: `mindepth` and `maxdepth` values are both `1`, so you probably don't need `find`, a `for` loop might suffice

Comment: in return i get this
$ ./change.sh 
./change.sh: line 2: Lawless: command not found
 here LawLess (1111) is name of first directory in list of directories.

Comment: If you can post *as text* a simple directory tree and files, that would be good to help others that want to help you understand what it is your dealing with.

Comment: 'Jack The Ripper (1988) [720p] [BluRay] [YTS.MX]'
'-Kalifornia (1993) [BluRay] [720p] [YTS.AM]'
'Lawless (2012)'
'Legend.2015.1080p.BluRay.X264-AMIABLE English'
'Legend (2015) [YTS.AG]'
 Mortal-Kombat-2021-WEBRip-x264-1619368644
Mortal.Kombat-.Legacy.S02E09.Liu.Kang.and.Shang.Tsung.Bluray-720p.en-mortal-kombat-legacy-second-season-english-1597023939
'Mortal Kombat Legends Battle Of The Realms (2021) [720p] [BluRay] [YTS.MX]'

Comment: One `.srt` file in one directory yes?

Comment: one .srt and one .mp4 in each subdir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the assumption that there is only one `.srt` file per directory, this might do what you wanted. Using a `while` + `read` loop and [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -rd '' files; do
  directory=${files%/*}
  (
    cd "$directory" || exit
    shopt -s nullglob
    for f in *.mp4 *.mkv; do
      printf '%s\n' "$f"
      file_name=${f%.*}
      echo mv -v -- *.srt "${file_name}.srt"
    done
  )
done < <(
  find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.mkv' \) -print0
)
```

---

- It can be probably done without the `cd` though but that is what I came up with, based on your script.

---

- Remove the `echo` if your satisfied with the output, so `mv` can actually rename/move the files.
- [How can read a file or strem line-by-line or field-by-field](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
- [How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)

Comment: got this$ ./change.sh 
./change.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./change.sh: line 8: `    for f in ./*.@(mp4|mkv); do'

Comment: Are you using `bash`? The script will not work with  `sh` and the likes

Comment: If you don't enable `extglob`  which is a `bash` feature then yeah, that error will occur. Run your script with `bash ./myscript.sh` and **NOT** `sh ./myscript.sh`

Comment: named but still  ./change 
./change: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./change: line 8: `    for f in ./*.@(mp4|mkv); do'

Comment: $ shopt extglob
extglob         on

 bash ./change 
./change: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./change: line 8: `    for f in ./*.@(mp4|mkv); do'

Comment: $ bash ./change 
./change: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./change: line 8: `    for f in ./*.@(mp4|mkv); do'

Comment: Right, please try now without that extglob thing.

Comment: still same error
$ shopt extglob
extglob         off
user@user:/media/user
$ bash ./change.sh 
./change.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./change.sh: line 8: `    for f in ./*.@(mp4|mkv); do'

Comment: I have updated/edited the script now, try it.

Comment: $ bash ./change.sh 
find: ‘’: No such file or directory

Comment: `./change.sh /path/to/your/directory` Change the argument `/path/to/your/directory` to the correct path.

Comment: no errors now. but but file names are not changed in subdirs, file names are also with spaces and commas

Comment: Remove the `echo` ONLY if you're sure that the output is what you expected. Also try the script in some dummy (back up the files really) files first before doing something bad.

Comment: script was perfect. it did work. however initial task was to traverse all subdirs in a dir and change file names. this only change filename to a single dir.

Comment: Remove the `-maxdepth 1` and `-mindepth 1` from `find` and put back the `echo` just to be sure.

Comment: Glad I could help, not sure why that `extglob` failed, Any ways that script was designed to work only with one movie file (either `.mp4` or `.mkv`) and one `.srt`  in any given directory. Obviously It can have more improvements but I'll leave that to you :-)